# How do I merge two unallocated, non-sequential partitions on the same logical disk?

Tags: partitioning, disk-space, disk-management, storage-spaces

I'm wondering if I could merge two unallocated spaces as shown in the picture below:

[image: Screenshot from Disk Management]

I would like to combine the two unallocated spaces into a single space for further partitioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's in a primary partition surrounded by unallocated space this should actually go pretty easily.

1. Ensure you make a full backup.
2. Get a disk partitioning utility.  Personally I like to use a LiveCD of [GPartEd](http://gparted.org/).
3. Use it to move the D: partition around to where you want it (slide it to one end of the unallocated space or the other kind of thing).
4. Apply changes, and take a nap while it applies them (could take *many hours* to complete).

Example/general UI picture of GPartEd:

[image]

Comment: If it isn't obvious enough: DO NOT POWER DOWN OR REBOOT DURING STEP 4.